# Custom class implementing interface IDictionary<type, type> that could be static?

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization

This is a bit [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and C# question. It seems to me this question will end up all about what c# CAN do so I'll post it here first.

I have a project that has multiple classes that need to access the same dataset. I have created a custom class for that dataset that has a private `Dictionary<byte[], MyCustomInterface>` instance. The class implements `IDictionary<byte[], MyCustomInterface>`. For the methods and properties I just wrap the private dictionary methods and properties. I have then added some methods and properties of my own dedicated to my specific needs.

As I said I need access to the custom dictionary and it's data in many classes. I tried making my custom class static but can't because it implements interfaces.

I **could** make a database in the background but that would be a way heavyweight solution. I have done this before but it ends up being a lot of maintenance.

What other ways would be available to have access to the same set of data/same class from all my classes? I need to be able to serialize/deserialize this custom data set and save the data in a file for retrieval later. I'd prefer to not give up on using Interfaces, they're really handy.

```
public class EntityDictionary : IDictionary<byte[], IDispenseEntity>
{
    private Dictionary<byte[], IDispenseEntity> _backing = new(new ByteArrayComparer());

    public IDispenseEntity this[byte[] key]
    {
        get => _backing[key]; 
        set => _backing[key] = value;
    }

    public ICollection<byte[]> Keys => _backing.Keys;

    public ICollection<IDispenseEntity> Values => _backing.Values;
    
    ...
    //My custom properties and methods
}
```

Comment: *I need access to the custom dictionary and it's data in many classes* - so, it's like a configuration singleton? And it could be injected?

Comment: Seems like you might want to make your class a singleton.  Additionally consider using composition instead of implementing `IDictionary` by having a `IDictionary` property on your class.

Comment: You really just need a static *instance* of your class, not to make the entire thing static. So somewhere have a static property like `public static EntityDictionary MySharedEntityDictionary { get; set; }`

Comment: Is concurrency going to be a thing to be worried about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton pattern?

```
public class EntityDictionary : IDictionary<byte[], IDispenseEntity>
{

    private EntityDictionary() {}
    static EntityDictionary() {}
    private static _instance = new EntityDictionary();
    public static Instance { get { return _instance; }}  

    ...

}
```

So there is only one dictionary that's shared by all uses, you can;t create your own instance, and are forced to use the single instance.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you.